Is this the end of life for my elderly Leopard Gecko?
Please help.
I have an 13 yr old Leopard Gecko. I bought her for my son when he was in middle school. He is well into adulthood, moved across the country and I decided to keep her so she didn't get stressed out.  In the last few months I have noticed she is molting all the time. She will go through a molt, be good and 2 weeks later molt again. She has also been looking very flat the last couple weeks. Today I noticed her tail looks more thinner than I've ever seen. She always has access to crickets, meal worms and fresh water. There are no exotic pet vets near me. Is this just the end of life or something else?

Just a side note: Crickets shouldn't stay in the gecko enclosure if they aren't eaten after a short time. Crickets can bite your gecko and cause stress and little skin lesions that might get infected.

okay so leopard geckos have a life-span of 10-20 years, but you might just be at the end.. hope you figure it out and that I helped! I love leopard geckos :)
